# want to parse a string in shell script

Tags: shell

I have a string in the format `foo="is a first one" foo1="is a second one" foo3="is a third one" and many fields like the said pattern. I want to parse this and have o/p as

```
foo              foo1              foo3
is a first one   is a second one   is a third one
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you already tried? Where have you already researched on this task? Did you encounter any problems?

Comment: I tried this with awk using FS commadn but didn't succed

Comment: Since you already tried `awk`, I'd recommend you move to perl rather than do this in the shell. It's quite simple there.

Comment: @Noufal, he probably hadn't tried hard enough. Awk is perfectly fine to do string parsing as Perl.

Comment: Probably but as time goes by, perl is generally more capable than awk in my experience.

Comment: I disagree with the close voters: seems pretty clear what suresh is asking.

Answer (score 2):

Columnizing the output is the hard part.  (I would agree with Noufal here that perl is a good way to go.)  However, it is doable with other more basic tools.  For example:

```
$ cat input
foo
is a first one
foo1
is a second one
foo3
is a third one
$ ( awk 'NR % 2' input; awk 'NR % 2 == 0' input ) | paste - - - | column -s'   ' -t
foo             foo1             foo3
is a first one  is a second one  is a third one
```

(Note that the -s argument to column should contain a tab between the single quotes.)

Answer (score 1):

Awk is perfectly fine to do string parsing.

```
s='foo="is a first one" foo1="is a second one" foo3="is a third one"'
echo $s | awk 'BEGIN{
    FS="\042 "
}
{
    c=NF
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
        m = split($i , a, "=")
        header[i] = a[1]
        content[i]= a[2]
    }
}
END{
    for(i=1;i<=c;i++){
        printf "%s\t", header[i]
    }
    print ""
    for(i=1;i<=c;i++){
        printf "%s\t", content[i]
    }
    print ""
}
'
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this  you wanted ?

```
   sed -nr 's/" /"\n/g;s/=/\n/gp' <<END  
    > foo="is a first one" foo1="is a second one" foo3="is a third one"
    > END
    foo
    "is a first one"
    foo1
    "is a second one"
    foo3
    "is a third one"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. It is working fine.Can you please explain me how it actually works and I also want the command to read input from a file. can you please correct it accordingly. It would be great if I can print data in a tabular form instead of printing it in lines.

Comment: i'm so sorry it's too late to reply,but i think you must got the better answer...

Answer (score 0):

Stealing the use of `column` from [William's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786393/want-to-parse-a-string-in-shell-script/5789253#5789253), this accepts the OP's suggested input. It requires the values to be double-quoted as per the sample input:

```
s='foo="is a first one" foo1="is a second one" foo3="is a third one"'
echo "$s" | awk -F'"' '
  {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=2) {
      sub(/^[[:space:]]*/, "", $i)
      sub(/=$/, "", $i)
      vars=vars $i "\t"
    }
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) {vals=vals $i "\t"}
  }
  END {print vars; print vals}
' | column -t -s $'\t'
```

outputs

```
foo             foo1             foo3
is a first one  is a second one  is a third one
```